# Browser creates connection to websocket repeatedly - socket.io

Tags: node.js, server, socket.io

I'm creating a socket.io and node.js server and it's saying there's many connections (every few minutes). It's creating a new id and it might interfere with other code that is using the id.

Server code:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var server = app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.static('public'));

var socket = require('socket.io');

var io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket) {
    console.log('new connection', socket.id);
}
```

And in the console, when run:

```
new connection 12naA3AGFfkjDPdnAAAM
new connection d_UeGFDAhsl401vFAAAN
new connection xBCBtiLMNOVX37-KAAAO
new connection RwmKzrVOGWRYeXNPAAAP
new connection 5NZ9WZ1-_k27brq5AAAQ
new connection QEbPMwPW69RYT15CAAAR
new connection 7qrEvvRYpAF0Yw1dAAAS
new connection -rV1aIgwrnPtZduyAAAT
new connection HUTJO5P1Z-Cg4iAjAAAU
new connection aPXmFpIu029CbUzZAAAV
new connection EkGupV-aaU5ePuCyAAAW
new connection E56CnnEXDryhFPGeAAAX
```

I'm not refreshing the page at all. How can I stop the server from connecting multiple times?

Comment: I may guess that socket.io cannot retrieve socket id that stored in browser and browser tries to reconnect repeatedly. So have You tried to attach cookie-parser? `app.use(require('cookie-parser')())`

Comment: I tried it, it says Error: Cannot find module 'cookie-parser'

Comment: it's a package. how about install?  (:   `npm i --save cookie-parser`

Comment: did You got any success? (:

Comment: It seems to be working so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may guess that `socket.io` cannot retrieve socket **id** that stored in browser's cookie storage.

When browser tries to reconnect after `101 Switching Protocols` it sends cookie, but backend party not parsing it from headers. As result socket.io cannot compare **id** that provided by **browser** with **id** in **memory**.

Try to attach [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser):

```
app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
```